# StackView Widget Sample source code

Tags: android, android-widget

Please provide StackView Widget example source code . http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html redirects to samples link http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html.

The Sample link suggests that the example can be found under "/samples/android-/" folder. But i didn't found any sample under these folders from api level 11 to 16 in my windows 7 PC.

In the [App widget section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) there are frequent references to this sample project but sadly i couldn't find the source. Please help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was missing a few developer demos too, but I finally found them in the SDK (updated to API17) docs subfolder:

\android-sdk\docs\resources\samples\StackWidget

So, actually, you had it all along!!

**Update (08/22/13):**

On Januari 27tht 2013 The folder mentioned above **DID** exist, however, after updating to Android 4.2 and 4.3 with ADT 22.05 the folder **...\samples\...** has been removed from the SDK and is no longer available.
Fortunately I still have both an untouched version and an eclipse project available. Get in touch if you would like a copy...

Comment: Actually there's no \docs\resources\samples directory. I've downloaded all samples but still no StackView example.

Comment: I can confirm the folder is present in older versions of the SDK. One would simply have to download an older SDK and look for the folder there (I personally found it in Android-4.0.1_r1.0-master/development/samples/StackWidget).

Answer (score 13):

I found a compressed tgz of the whole branch here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/StackWidget

7-zip should be able to unpack tgz

Answer (score 8):

its over here if you are still looking for it

http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/

Answer (score 1):

Check Vogella's Github here:
https://github.com/vogellacompany/android-examples/tree/master/com.vogella.android.stackview.activity

You can clone or download from here:
https://github.com/vogellacompany/android-examples.git

You can find stack widget demo under "com.example.android.stackwidget" directory

Comment: This example is not related to app widget. Actually it's project called com.example.android.stackwidget. Please correct url in your answer. It should be:
https://github.com/vogella/vogella/tree/master/com.example.android.stackwidget