# Android start activity when pressing widget ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, widget, click

I'm working on a ListView widget where I want the user to be able to launch a activity when the ListView is clicked. I haven't been able to find any sort of tutorial on this so I'm wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or perhaps share some code. I want to launch the same activity regardless of which ListItem is clicked so that's not a problem.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#implementing_collections) and scroll to the subheading **Adding behavior to individual items**.

You need to make sure you call both `setPendingIntentTemplate()` from your `AppWidgetProvider` *and* `setOnClickFillInIntent()` from your `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` implementation.

For example:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    // ...

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){

            RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, myActivity.class);
            PendingIntent startActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list_view, startActivityPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);

            // ...
    }
}

public class WidgetAdapter implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    // ...

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews widgetRow = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_row);

        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtra(Widget.EXTRA_LIST_VIEW_ROW_NUMBER, position);
        widgetRow.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.list_view_row, fillInIntent);

        // ...

        return widgetRow;
    }
}
```

There is a more conclusive example in the StackWidget sample which is in the [SDK samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html), although I found it somewhat difficult to find (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071802/stackview-widget-sample-source-code) for directions). It creates an intent to show a Toast message, but it uses the same code.

Comment: it seems it gets all the data in the ListView so when going to the activity it doesn't return the correct extra you putted. How to solve this?

Comment: could you help me? here's mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587137/how-to-get-the-clicked-item-from-listview-of-a-widget-android thank you.

Answer (score -10):

To launch any Activity you create an Intent and then call startActivity on that intent. Check Intent and startActivity and I am sure you will able to do it yourself.

Comment: Of course I know how to launch a activity the ordinary way. I'm wondering about how you do it with a ListView widget since the ordinary PendingIntent won't work.