# How to get Click event on List Item of Home Screen widget in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-widget, android-appwidget-list

**Issue**

- I have widget on homescreen with Listview which dynamic data item, now
  can I get click event on listview item click.
  As I can get click of another button on widget but still not success on list item click.

**SimpleWidgetProvider.Java**

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String UPDATE_ACTION = "ActionUpdateSinglenoteWidget";
public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.varshaaweblabs.estateblock.TOAST_ACTION";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.varshaaweblabs.estateblock.EXTRA_ITEM";
private static final String MyButton1 = "mybutton1";
private static final String MyButton2 = "mybutton2";
static RemoteViews remoteViews;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static SharedPreferences pref;
public Call<Search_Response> registerResponseCall;
ArrayList<Listing> listItemList = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson1 = new Gson();
public static GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<String> jarray = new ArrayList<>();
public Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

public void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            final int appWidgetId) {
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("estateblock", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();

    getData(context, MyButton1);
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_current, "setBackgroundColor", Color.MAGENTA);
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_home, "setBackgroundColor", Color.LTGRAY);
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_seeall, "setBackgroundColor", Color.MAGENTA);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Set up the collection
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                setRemoteAdapter(context, remoteViews);
            } else {
                setRemoteAdapterV11(context, remoteViews);
            }
            // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_current, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyButton1));
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_home, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyButton2));
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progress, View.GONE);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_list, View.VISIBLE);
            pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
            notifyUpdate(context, remoteViews);

        }
    }, 5000);
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }


    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

/**
 * Sets the remote adapter used to fill in the list items
 *
 * @param views RemoteViews to set the RemoteAdapter
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private static void setRemoteAdapter(Context context, @NonNull final RemoteViews views) {
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list,
            new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));


}

/**
 * Sets the remote adapter used to fill in the list items
 *
 * @param views RemoteViews to set the RemoteAdapter
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void setRemoteAdapterV11(Context context, @NonNull final RemoteViews views) {
    views.setRemoteAdapter(0, R.id.widget_list,
            new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));
}


protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {


    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);



}

public void notifyUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {

    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int appWidgetIds[] = manager.getAppWidgetIds(
            new ComponentName(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class));
    manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_list);


    hideProgress(remoteViews, context);
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Touched view " + viewIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (MyButton1.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("estateblock", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        listItemList.clear();
        updateData(context, MyButton1);


        Toast.makeText(context, "Current Criteria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (MyButton2.equals(intent.getAction())) {


        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("estateblock", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        listItemList.clear();
        updateData(context, MyButton2);

    }

}


private void updateData(final Context context, String myButton) {

    if (myButton.equalsIgnoreCase("mybutton1")) {
        final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        showProgress(remoteViews, context);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_home, "setBackgroundColor", Color.LTGRAY);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_current, "setBackgroundColor", Color.MAGENTA);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

        configIntent.putExtra("widget", "Current");


        configIntent.setAction("current");

        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_seeall, configPendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Current", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);

        getData(context, MyButton1);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                notifyUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);

            }
        }, 3500);

    }

    if (myButton.equalsIgnoreCase("mybutton2")) {
        final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        showProgress(remoteViews, context);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_home, "setBackgroundColor", Color.MAGENTA);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_current, "setBackgroundColor", Color.LTGRAY);

        Intent configIntent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

        configIntent1.putExtra("widget", "Home");

        configIntent1.setAction("Home");


        PendingIntent configPendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, configIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_seeall, configPendingIntent1);


        Toast.makeText(context, "All Homes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
        getData(context, MyButton2);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                notifyUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
            }
        }, 3500);

    }
}
```

}

**ListProvider.java**

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;
List<Listing> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mCollection = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Listing> listItemList = new ArrayList<>();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences pref;
Gson gson = new Gson();


public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;


    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Utility.APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    Log.e("Constructor", "Called");
    populateListItem();

}


public void populateListItem() {

    listItemList.clear();

    String arrayListString = pref.getString("widget", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Listing>>() {
    }.getType();

    listItemList = gson.fromJson(arrayListString, type);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.grid_view);

    Bitmap image = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(listItemList.get(position).getPrimaryPhoto().getUrl().getThumb());
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Image_load", e.getMessage());
    }
    remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_item_app_icon, image);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItemList.get(position).getPriceForMap());
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.address, listItemList.get(position).getArea());


    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Propertyfulldetailactivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    intent.putExtra(Utility.LISTING_KEY, listItemList.get(position).getListingKey());
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST", (Serializable) listItemList.get(position));
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_item_app_icon, pendingIntent);


    return remoteView;
}


@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {


    Log.e("onCreate", "Called");
    populateListItem();

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {

    populateListItem();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}
```

}

- So please refer my code and try to help me out with this issue.

Comment: Do you want to close your app and to display phone's home screen?

Comment: if i click on listView item then open other activity ??

Comment: Yes, i want open other activity from widget contex when app is killed.

Comment: The [accepted answer on the first linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14811595) clearly explains what you need to do. Next time, include your code in the question from the start.

Comment: Why did a different user provide the code, and therefore >90% of the content, in your question?

Comment: @MikeM. I checked your First Link and done that implementation but it did not worked in my case.

Comment: Please indicate exactly where in the posted code `setPendingIntentTemplate()` is being called on the content `RemoteViews` for your Widget, and `setOnClickFillInIntent()` is being called on the list items' `RemoteViews` in the `RemoteViewsFactory`.

Comment: Same as per your First Link @MikeM. Sir.

Comment: Uh, no they're not. Neither of those methods appear in the code posted in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple to add a item click listener in list-view. You just take a look in [Android List-view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) link.

Comment: He is not asking for the activity. Setting listener for listeview is different in widgets...