# How to advance automatically StackView items on a Widget

Tags: android, widget, appwidgetprovider, stackview

I'm making a StackView Widget for my app, i got the Google example available here and used it :
[StackView Widget Sample source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071802/stackview-widget-sample-source-code)

When i launched the example on my phone inoticed that the widget items advance automatically each few seconds.

But i can't get this behaviour on my widget, i looked everywhere in the example code i can't define what is making the items advance automatically.

I added also the attribute android:autoAdvanceViewId to the AppWidgetProviderInfo element but this is not working.

If someone know how this works this will be helpful.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The attribute **android:autoAdvanceViewId** works !

I deleted the widget then added it to the home screen to take changes.

Problem solved.